# MongoDB Mongoose - Missing default fields on text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a product schema that looks something like this:

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: String,

  comments: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Comment' }],
  comment_count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

And index for text search the name and description:

```
ProductSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text' });
```

I use the text search like so:

```
this.find(
  { $text: { $search: keywords } },
  { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
.sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.populate({
  path: 'comments',
  select: 'creator body date_created',
  options: {
    sort: { date_created: -1 }
  }
})
.exec( function(products) {
  ... //-> snipped for brevity
});
```

Although the search works just fine, some items on the returned data set do not have a `comment_count` field which is supposed to default to 0.
The problem I think is when I try to return the the text search score because when I remove this line: `{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }`. All items on the list have a comment_count field.

I would like to make both work, as it makes a lot of sense to sort the data by text score.

NOTE:
I'd like to note that I call `this` during the search query because I placed this as a static method for `Product`.

I'd also like to note that `comment_count` is changed whenever a comment is added or deleted and isn't being populated during the search query. Not sure if this info might be helpful of if relevant at all, though.

Comment: Did you try to start from a completely new collection? If you added `comment_count` (or default value) after you had some records those ones didn't get default values automatically.

Comment: I think Michelem has the right idea.  Personally, I would go into MongoVUE (an application to view MongoDB databases), go to the collection in question and review the data using the table view.  MongoDB stores collections of document objects rather than the approach of a SQL database which is a set of identical-formatted records.

Comment: @Mich That's what I thought too, but why would the `comment_count` data be correct if I removed the the `{ score .. }` line? That's where it doesn't make sense.

Also, thank you for mongoVUE. I use robomongo but it seems lacking to me. I'll try it out.